# При подключении через браузер ServerSocket выдает 2 сокета

Tags: java

MyServer.java
//

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class MyServer {
    public static final int DEFAULT_PORT=50107;
    private int PORT=DEFAULT_PORT;
    public MyServer() {

    }

    public MyServer(int PORT) {
        this.PORT = PORT;
    }

    public void start(){
        ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);

            while (true) {
                Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                System.out.println("Connection:" + socket.getLocalAddress());
                //ClientThread clientThread = new ClientThread(socket);
                //System.out.println(clientThread.getThread().getName()+" has started");
                //clientThread.getThread().start();

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Main
//

```
public class Lab5Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyServer server=new MyServer();
        server.start();


    }

}
```

[image: два подключения]

Comment: Вопрос в том :"Почему 2 сокета? с одного я считываю байты, другой пуст" потому что нигде больше не происходит подключение, по коду- это очевидно

Comment: подключаюсь 1 раз

Comment: Посмотрите в консоли отладки браузера сколько запросов делает браузер.